# Is this action a shirk?

Tags: halal-haram

As Salam alaikum, brothers. There is a question. I'm playing a game in which, for example, there are different statues of different creatures (like the statues of those Egyptian idols). And just for the game currency I buy and place on my account to increase the combat power of the account. In no way am I doing this as a worship of these creatures! Never. And here's the question. Is my given action a shirk and a sin? Did you come out of religion? [image]

Comment: Do you really know what "shirk" means ? Reading a definition will answer your question.

Comment: So it's not Shirk? But it is a sin. Yes?

Comment: So you cannot look at a pig (not even a virtual one)?

Comment: in what sense??

Comment: I just want to know if this is a shirk. And is this a sin? That's all. In this game there are such achievements (Titles giving an increase in strength) "God Shinobi". That's why I'm asking

Comment: What you describe makes me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth_(deadly_sin) which, in my very personal opinion, is the direct counterpart of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jihad . With the first, you sin by wasting time (and money, in your case) with the second, you fail to make yourself useful, not only for others but also for you, yourself.

Comment: In this game I spend at most about 1.5 hours a day. The rest of the time is prayer, which I do right away. I read the Quran 2 pages a day and do my job. Is this a waste of time considered a sin? And in other cases not?